# Error when import a save file in Tkinter with Python

Tags: python, tkinter, runtime-error

I have this problem in Tkinter. I wish to import a file (*.txt) with Open Button and save some values with Save Button. I wish to show a Error message when no file is open.

I am wrong becuse i get always this message:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1470, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/samsung/PycharmProjects/test_FirstDensity/openANDread.py", line 30, in save
    if not self.filename.name:
AttributeError: MainWindow instance has no attribute 'filename'
```

This is a very simplify example

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
import Tkinter, Tkconstants, tkFileDialog

class MainWindow(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.master.title("input")
        self.master.minsize(250, 150)
        self.grid(sticky=E+W+N+S)

        top=self.winfo_toplevel()
        top.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        top.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        for i in range(2):self.rowconfigure(i, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

        self.button0 = Button(self, text="open", command=self.askopenfilename, activeforeground="red")
        self.button0.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=2, padx=2, sticky=E+W+N+S)

        self.button1 = Button(self, text="save", command=self.save, activeforeground="red")
        self.button1.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=2, padx=2, sticky=E+W+N+S)

    def askopenfilename(self):
        self.filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Text Files",'.txt')])
        return self.filename.name

    def save(self):
        if not self.filename.name:
            tkMessageBox.showerror("Error", message="None file to save")
            return
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are calling the `save()` method before calling the `askopenfilename()` method. That's why, you get the `AttributeError`. Make sure the flow of your code reflects this change.

You might also want to include proper error handling in your `askopenfilename()` method itself to include situations where no file is opened.

You could do something on these lines. First initialize the `self.filename = None` in your constructor for the `MainWindow` class. Then you could modify your method as such:

```
def askopenfilename(self):
        self.filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Text Files",'.txt')])
        if not self.filename: return None
        return self.filename.name
```

However this is just to give you an idea, I have not myself worked with `Tkinter` much. All in all, it would depend on what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: You don't need to return anything, because the `Button` widget won't do anything with the return value. After the `if not self.filename:` line, just popup your messagebox. Otherwise, `self.filename` will have the value of the file name.